# umap-project can't find vendor libraries

Tags: python, django, leaflet

I am trying to extend umap (https://github.com/umap-project/umap), I used git clone to get the latest version of umap code and imported it into eclipse. I have PyDev Django environment set up. According to the installation guide I created configuration file (/etc/umap/umap.conf), created database, run manage.py migrate and collectstatic. Everything went ok.
Home page is displayed also ok, but when I try to do anything (login, create map) I get stack of errors.
Please find below log from eclipse console. I am looking at github repo and also cannot find this folder /static/umap/vendors. I just started to work with umap so maybe I am missing something.

```
Loaded local config from /etc/umap/umap.conf
/home/svranic/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
Loaded local config from /etc/umap/umap.conf
/home/svranic/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 12, 2018 - 11:32:32
Django version 2.1.1, using settings 'umap.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:38] "GET /en/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10859
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:38] "GET /static/umap/vendors/leaflet/leaflet.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1834
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:38] "GET /static/umap/vendors/contextmenu/leaflet.contextmenu.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1882
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:38] "GET /static/umap/vendors/markercluster/MarkerCluster.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1870
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:38] "GET /static/umap/vendors/markercluster/MarkerCluster.Default.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1894
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:38] "GET /static/umap/vendors/minimap/Control.MiniMap.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1858
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:38] "GET /static/umap/vendors/editinosm/Leaflet.EditInOSM.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1870
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:38] "GET /static/umap/vendors/measurable/Leaflet.Measurable.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1876
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:38] "GET /static/umap/vendors/toolbar/leaflet.toolbar.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1858
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:38] "GET /static/umap/font.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:38] "GET /static/umap/vendors/fullscreen/leaflet.fullscreen.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1876
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:38] "GET /static/umap/base.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:38] "GET /static/umap/content.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:38] "GET /static/umap/nav.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:38] "GET /static/umap/map.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:38] "GET /static/umap/vendors/editable/Path.Drag.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1840
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:38] "GET /static/umap/theme.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:38] "GET /static/umap/vendors/i18n/Leaflet.i18n.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1837
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/hash/leaflet-hash.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1837
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/togeojson/togeojson.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1843
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/minimap/Control.MiniMap.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1855
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/osmtogeojson/osmtogeojson.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1861
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/markercluster/leaflet.markercluster-src.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1903
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/fullscreen/Leaflet.fullscreen.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1873
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/contextmenu/leaflet.contextmenu.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1879
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/georsstogeojson/GeoRSSToGeoJSON.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1879
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/photon/leaflet.photon.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1849
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/heat/leaflet-heat.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1837
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/formbuilder/Leaflet.FormBuilder.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1879
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/toolbar/leaflet.toolbar-src.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1867
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/js/umap.core.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/measurable/Leaflet.Measurable.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1873
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/togpx/togpx.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1819
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/js/umap.autocomplete.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/tokml/tokml.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1819
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/js/umap.popup.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/js/umap.icon.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/js/umap.forms.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/js/umap.controls.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/js/umap.features.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/js/umap.slideshow.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/js/umap.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/editable/Leaflet.Editable.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1861
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/loading/Control.Loading.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1855
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/js/umap.xhr.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/js/umap.permissions.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/leaflet/leaflet-src.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1843
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/js/umap.ui.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/editable/Path.Drag.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1840
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/js/umap.tableeditor.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/csv2geojson/csv2geojson.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1855
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/editinosm/Leaflet.EditInOSM.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1867
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/js/umap.layer.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/img/osm.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/img/edit.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/img/opensource.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/editable/Leaflet.Editable.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1861
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/hash/leaflet-hash.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1837
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/i18n/Leaflet.i18n.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1837
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/editinosm/Leaflet.EditInOSM.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1867
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/minimap/Control.MiniMap.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1855
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/csv2geojson/csv2geojson.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1855
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/togeojson/togeojson.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1843
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/osmtogeojson/osmtogeojson.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1861
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/loading/Control.Loading.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1855
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/markercluster/leaflet.markercluster-src.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1903
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/contextmenu/leaflet.contextmenu.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1879
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/photon/leaflet.photon.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1849
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/georsstogeojson/GeoRSSToGeoJSON.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1879
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/heat/leaflet-heat.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1837
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/fullscreen/Leaflet.fullscreen.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1873
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/toolbar/leaflet.toolbar-src.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1867
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/formbuilder/Leaflet.FormBuilder.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1879
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/measurable/Leaflet.Measurable.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1873
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/togpx/togpx.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1819
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/vendors/tokml/tokml.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1819
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/img/logo.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/font/FiraSans-SemiBold.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/font/FiraSans-Light.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[12/Sep/2018 11:32:39] "GET /static/umap/img/logo_filigree.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer on github. If anyone has same issue, answer can be found on following link: https://github.com/umap-project/umap/issues/638.